# Spaghetti plot with one factor

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, facet

I have a dataframe

```
df_A<-data.frame(cost=ceiling(c(1:100)/10),
                 gamma=c(1:10),
                 error=sample(0:10, 100, replace=TRUE),
                 id="Test")

df_B<-data.frame(cost=ceiling(c(1:100)/10),
                 gamma=c(1:10),
                 error=sample(0:10, 100, replace=TRUE),
                 id="Validation")

df_A_B<-rbind(df_A, df_B)
```

I do a spaghetti plot factor them by ID and Gamma

```
ggplot(df_A_B, aes(x=cost, y=error, color=factor(gamma), fill=interaction(id, gamma))) + 
  geom_line()+geom_point()+theme_bw()+scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0,10))
```

and the results is

[image]

and is ok, now I would make a plot like this:

[image]

where the same Gamma is colored and other are grey, for all Gamma, how can I do?

Thanks you very much

P.s.
Sorry for my English

Comment: You can split the graph into panels with `facet_wrap`, but what variable did you want to use to define each panel? `gamma`? The highlighting of a single line can be done with the `{gghighlight}` package. If you explain your question more, I can give a full answer with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code will produce the following plot using the package {gghighlight}.

```
ggplot(df_A_B, aes(x=cost, y=error, color=factor(gamma), fill=interaction(id, gamma))) + 
  geom_line() + 
  geom_point() + 
  theme_bw() + 
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0,10)) +
  facet_wrap(~gamma) + 
  gghighlight()
```

[image]

Comment: if you were thinking of grouping on some other variable, please update your question :)